# Question about boundary of super-level sets of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, functions, differential-geometry

I want to prove the following statement.

> Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f \in C^0
>  (\Omega;\mathbb{R})$. Then, for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ $$\partial
>  \left\{ f > r \right\} \subseteq \left\{ f =r \right\},$$ where
>    $\partial$ denotes the topological boundary and $\left\{ f > r
>  \right\}=\left\{ x \in \Omega : f(x) > r \right\}$.

**My attempt**: Suppose by absurd that there exists $\bar{x} \in \partial \left\{ f > r \right\}$ such that $f (\bar{x}) > r$. By continuity, there exists an open neighborhood $U_{\bar{x}}$ of $\bar{x}$ such that:
$$f (y) > r \quad \forall \; y \in U_{\bar{x}},$$
i.e. $U_{\bar{x}} \subseteq \left\{ f > r \right\}$ and then
$$U_{\bar{x}} \cap \left\{ f > r \right\}^c=\emptyset,$$
and this is an absurd with the definition of $\partial \left\{ f > r \right\}$. Similarly for the case $f(\bar{x}) < r$ and then $$\bar{x} \in \partial \left\{ f > r \right\}  \quad \Rightarrow f(\bar{x})=r.$$

Is it correct?
Thanks

Comment: First of all it's not true that $\bar{x}$ exists. The boundary might be empty.

Comment: If I add the hypothesis $\partial \left\{ f > r \right\} \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: It's still not enough. Take $f(x)=x$ and $r=0$. Then $x=0$ is the only boundary point, $x\in\partial \{f>0\}$ but $f(\bar{x})=0$.

Comment: Furthermore, the existence of the neighborhood $U_x$ isn't guaranteed just by continuity. The function $f(x)=x$ with $r=0$ shows this as well. There is no neighborhood $U_x$ of $x=0$ such that $U_x\subset\{f>0\}$.

Comment: Sorry TSF I can't undestand your second-last comment: let $f(x)=x$, then $\partial \left\{ f > 0 \right\}=\left\{ 0 \right\}$ and $f(0)=0$, where is the mistake with my statement?

Comment: You wrote, "let $\bar{x} \in \partial \left\{ f > r \right\}$ such that $f (\bar{x}) > r$." Translated into our context is means, "let $\bar{x} \in \partial \left\{ f > 0 \right\}$ such that $f (\bar{x}) > 0$. As you noted, $f(\bar{x})=0$ necessarily here.

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand. But this is the hypothesis by absurd. I can't follow your argument. In your example $\partial \left\{ f > 0 \right\}=\left\{f= 0 \right\}$ and it agress with my statement. Can you explain better why the statement is wrong?

Comment: I edited the question, maybe it's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You arguments are correct (provided the boundary is taken in $\Omega$, but not in $\Bbb R^n$, 
otherwise the boundary can have points outside $\Omega$, in which $f$ is undefined).

PS. Instead "by absurd" I usually write "to the contrary".