# A sublevel set and its boundary of a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, differential-topology

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
I am going to show the following proposition:

> For a differentiable function $f:\R^n \to \R$, the boundary $\partial A$ of the $c$-sublevel set $A = \{x \in \R^n~|~f(x) \le c\}$ is equal to $B := \{x \in \R^n~|~f(x) = c\}$ if $\nabla f (x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \R^n$.

Attempted proof:
It is known that $\partial A \subseteq B$. [Papemax89](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3682091/334795) Therefore, it suffices to show that $B \subseteq \partial A$.

Let $x \in B$, or $f(x) = c$. The goal is to show that $x \in \partial A$. Suppose $x \notin \partial A = \bar {A} \setminus A^\circ$, or equivalently, $x \notin \bar{A}$ or $x \in A^\circ$. However, $x \notin \bar{A} = A$ ($\because A$ is closed), or, $f(x) > c$, yields a contradiction. On the other hand, if we assume $ x \in A^\circ$, there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_\epsilon (x) \subseteq A^\circ \subseteq A$, that is, for all $y \in B_\epsilon (x)$, we have $f(y) \le c$. Since $f(x) = c$, $x$ is a local maximizer of $f$. Thus, $\nabla f (x) = 0$, which is a contradiction.

Is this correct? I want to know if there is a more succinct proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks correct to me. As an alternative one can do a direct proof by using the fact that if $\nabla f(x) \ne 0$ then $f$ increases in the direction of $\nabla f(x)$, and decreases in the opposite direction.

So we consider the function
$$
 h: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \, , \, h(t) = f(x + t \nabla f(x)) \, .
$$
If $f(x) = c$ then $h(0) = c$ and $h'(0) = \Vert \nabla f(x) \Vert^2 >0$. It follows that
$$
 h(-\epsilon) = f(x - \epsilon \nabla f(x)) < c \, , \\
 h(\epsilon) = f(x + \epsilon \nabla f(x)) > c \, 
$$
or $x - \epsilon \nabla f(x) \in A^0$ and $x + \epsilon \nabla f(x) \in \bar A^C$ for all sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$, and that proves that $x \in \partial A$.