# Given nonvanishing gradient, determine if $bdy(\{f<a\})=\{f=a\}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I don't know if it matters, but let us assume $M$ is a smooth manifold without (manifold) boundary, which is symbolized by $\partial M=\emptyset$. Now suppose $f:M\to\Bbb R$ is a smooth function on $M$. Given $a\in\Bbb R$, I was wondering if it is possible to prove or disprove that the (topological) boundary $bdy(\{x:f(x)<a\})$ of the strict sub-level set $\{x:f(x)<a\}$ is equal to $\{x:f(x)=a\}$.

*Edit 1:* Since $f$ is smooth, it is continuous, which shows $\{f<a\}$ is open. Then $bdy(\{f<a\})$ is equal to the difference of the closure of $\{f<a\}$ and $\{f<a\}$. In symbols, we write
$$bdy(\{f<a\})=\overline{\{f<a\}}\setminus\{f<a\}.$$
Now it is tempting to show that $\overline{\{f<a\}}=\{f\leq a\}$. But when I was doing it, all that came into my mind was to express $\{f<a\}$ as

[image]

Does it help any? This is a countable union of closed sets, so there seems to be no point in saying that the union is closed. And I'm stuck here. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

*Edit 2:* **Thanks to @AnCar, we have a counter-example (see the comment). Now, to make the equality come true, we might have to require that the gradient $\mathrm{grad\ } f$ of $f$ should not vanish somewhere, which presumes $M$ to be endowed with a Riemannian metric $g$. So let me update the question as follows. Given a smooth real-valued function $f$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ without boundary, can we prove or disprove
$$bdy(\{f<a\})=\{f=a\}$$
if $\mathrm{grad\ } f\neq 0$ everywhere?** To prove $bdy(\{f<a\})\subseteq\{f=a\}$, we begin by randomly selecting
$$x_0\in\overline{\{f<a\}}\cap\{f\geq a\}=bdy(\{f<a\}).$$
Since $f(x_0)\geq a$, we can divide the proof into two parts. The first one comes to us when we consider $f(x_0)=a$, which makes certain of the inclusion. So we proceed to consider the second part, in which $f(x_0)>a$. Now, $f$ is continuous, so we can find a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ so that $f>a$ on $U$. Clearly, $U$ does not intersect $\{f<a\}$, which makes $x_0$ unable to fall into the closure, a contradiction. Now we can move on to determine if the other inclusion is true:
$$\{f=a\}\overset{\color{red}?}{\subseteq}bdy(\{f<a\})$$
This is where I get lost. If $(M,g)$ is simply the real axis $\Bbb R$ with the standard metric, I can obtain the desired result, though. In this case, whenever $x_0\in\{f=a\}$, every open ball centered at $x_0$ will contain points where $f<a$ and points where $f>a$ because $f'(x_0)\neq 0$. This implies $x\in bdy(\{f<a\})$. Now, how can I generalize this argument to an abstract Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, especially when there is this bugaboo $\mathrm{grad\ } f\neq 0$? I need some help, please. By the way, does my question have to do with regular values? Thank you.

Comment: What if your function is constant on an open set? Could you still have that the boundary is all of the level set $\{x:f(x)=a\}$?

Comment: @AnCar Are you suggesting that the desired result might be an illusion? Thank you.

Comment: Well unless i misunderstood what you meant, consider $M=(-1,2)$ and take a function $f$ that is $0$ on $(-1,0]$ , $1$ on $[1,2)$ and strictly between $0$ and $1$ on $(0,1)$ such that it is also smooth. Then $\{f<1\}=(-1,1)$ and $\{f=1\}=[1,2)$. Clearly not the boundary of $\{f<1\}$ in the relative topology.

Comment: @AnCar Thanks for your clear example. Will it get better if I impose the assumption that $\mathsf{grad} f\neq 0$? I got this from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4541426/a-sublevel-set-and-its-boundary-of-a-differentiable-function.

Comment: But doesn't that post and the other referenced within already answer your question? Remember that a smooth manifold is locally diffeomorphic and therefore homeomorphic to a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the appropriate dimension. This means that the composition of the atlas map (or the inverse of it) with $f$ will preserve all openness and closedness properties.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a differential geometry guy, so I don't feel comfortable writing this in the language of Riemannian manifolds. I will just assume that $M$ is a smooth manifold and that $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function with non-zero gradient.

For arbitrary $a\in\mathbb{R}$, set $M_{a,-}:=\{x\in M: f(x)<a\}$, $M_{a,+}:=\{x\in M: f(x)>a\}$ and $M_a:=\{x\in M: f(x)=a\}$. The question then becomes to show that $\overline{M_{a,-}}\setminus M_{a,-}^\circ=M_a$.

Let us also observe that $M_{a,-}^\circ=M_{a,-}$ simply because $f$ is continuous and $M_{a,-}$ is the preimage of the open set $(-\infty,a)$ through the continuous map $f$.

In order to show the first inclusion `$\subseteq$', it therefore suffices to show that $\overline{M_{a,-}}\cap M_{a,+}=\varnothing$. This is straightforward, as already showed in the original post. If $x\in \overline{M_{a,-}}\cap M_{a,+}$, then for $y$ in a small neighborhood of $x$ we would have that $f(y)>a$, meaning that $x$ cannot be a limit point of $M_{a,-}$.

We are left to show the other inclusion `$\supseteq$'. For this, since clearly $M_a\cap M_{a,-}= \varnothing$, we just need to argue that $M_a\subseteq \overline{M_{a,-}}$. So let $x\in M_a$ be arbitrary, i.e., let $x\in M$ such that $f(x)=a$ be arbitrary. We need to show that for any open neighborhood $U\subset M$ containing $x$, we must have that $U\cap M_{a,-}\neq\varnothing$, i.e., that there exists some $y\in U$ such that $f(y)<a$.

So let us assume that there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(y)\geq a$ for all $y\in U$. Note that this property will be preserved for any included neighborhood that still contains $x$. So, by possibly relabeling $U$, we can apply the definition of a smooth manifold to find a diffeomorphic chart map $\phi:B\to U$ satisfying $\phi(0)=x$, where $B$ is the unit open ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d$ being the manifold dimension of $M$.

Note that $(f\circ\phi)(B)\subset[a,\infty)$ by our assumption on $U$. However, $(f\circ\phi)(0)=a$, so $0$ is a minimum of the differentiable map $f\circ\phi$. Therefore, $\nabla (f\circ\phi)(0)=0$. By the chain rule, since $\phi$ is a diffeomorphishm, this means that $\nabla f$ must have a $0$, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how could you build up the gradient without a Riemannian metric?

Comment: You stated the question initially as concerning a smooth map on a differential manifold. What do you mean? As long as you have a smooth atlas, you can do calculus on the manifold, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold. As I have said, I am not a differential geometry expert. I don't believe having a differential manifold is the same as having a Riemannian manifold. My point is that a smooth manifold is enough for what you require.

Comment: @Wombat so what is missing? is a Riemannian manifold not a differentiable manifold according to your definition?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to make you feel uncomfortable, but I really need someone to help me get the desired inclusion using the geometric gradient $\nabla_g$. I'm sure your attempt does make sense in your interpretation, and I really appreciate it, but the idea of taking $\nabla (f\circ\phi)$ is somewhat strange to me.

Comment: @Wombat no need to apologize, you didn't make me uncomfortable. this idea of dealing with maps via the atlas is the usual way of formalizing stuff on manifolds as far as I know. How do you define $\nabla_g f$?

Comment: Thank you. Given a smooth function $f$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, we define its gradient $\nabla f$ to be the vector field $(df)^\sharp$ on $M$ with $\sharp$ symbolic of raising an index by $g$. In local coordinates $(x^i)$, we have $$\nabla f=g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}.$$ Please notice that we have implemented the Einstein summation convention.

Comment: @Wombat Sorry, I am really not knowledgeable enough in differential geometry to translate this problem to the metric setting. The result you are looking for is true though since, at least as far as I know, a Riemannian manifold is a smooth manifold.

Comment: That's OK. You have done a lot for me. If everyone meets a few angels every day, you are one of the angels I met today. Thank you.